# What is the equivalent of Java `Collection.addAll` for JavaScript arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Java Collections have a method to add all elements of another collection: [`addAll(Collection other)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#addAll(java.util.Collection)).

What is the equivalent to do in place appending of javascript arrays?

We cannot use [`Array.concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat), because it creates a new array and leaves the original array untouched.

So, given two arrays, how `b` to `a`, how to append all elements of `b` to `a` in place (therefore `c` also changes!):

```
var a = [1, 2, 3];
var b = ['foo', 'bar'];
var c = a;
// a.addAll(b);
// so that `c` equals to  [1, 2, 3, 'foo', 'bar']
```

Answer (score 82, accepted):

You can use the `apply` method of [`Array.prototype.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push):

```
var a = [1, 2, 3];
var b = ['foo', 'bar'];
Array.prototype.push.apply(a, b);
console.log(a); // Array [ 1, 2, 3, "foo", "bar" ]
```

or alternatively:

```
a.push.apply(a, b);
[].push.apply(a, b);
```

If you're using ES6, it's better to call `.push()` using [the spread operator `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) instead. This is more similar to `Collection.addAll(...)` because you can add values from any [iterable object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols), not just arrays. It also allows you to add multiple iterables at once.

```
const a = [1, 2, 3];
const b = ['foo', 'bar'];
const c = new Set(['x', 'x', 'y', 'x']);
a.push(...b, ...c);
console.log(a); // Array [ 1, 2, 3, "foo", "bar", "x", "y" ]
```

Comment: @A.Wolff That's an very different operation -- this extends an existing array, that creates a new one.

Comment: You can also use `a.push.apply(a, b);`.

Comment: @Andy if only madox2 had thought of that!!

Comment: @JeremyBanks I was sure to miss something

Comment: @Pointy, just saying it's shorter. Jeez.

Comment: I did not realize that `push` takes a list of arguments

Comment: Thanks. I'm using `a.push(...b)`.